# VBA copy data from other file - problem with file name change

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to copy data from other file without opening, then paste data to my workbook to sheet PASTEHERE.
How can I use this code if the target file name is changing - I want to select that file by text contain which is always stable: "RB".

```vb
Sub DownloadRA()
    Dim rgTarget As Range
    Set rgTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PASTEHERE").Range("B23:EA6000") 'destination file .
    rgTarget.FormulaArray = "='D:\2023 MOJE pliki tygodniowe\kopie zapasowe\[2023.W01 RB File 03012023.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$23:$EA$6000"
    rgTarget.Formula = rgTarget.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the target file the file containing the code? In that case I recommend you use `Set rgTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PASTEHERE").Range("B23:EA6000")`. To get the current name of the target file, use `ThisWorkbook.Name`, or, if I wrongly assumed it is there file containing the code, use `ActiveWorkbook.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dir() to check for the source file.  Note this will only pick the first match it finds - if you might have >1 file you would need to explain how to select the "correct" one...

```vb
Sub DownloadRA()
    Const FLDR As String = "D:\2023 MOJE pliki tygodniowe\kopie zapasowe\"
    Dim rgTarget As Range, f
    Set rgTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PASTEHERE").Range("B23:EA6000") 'destination file .
    
    f = Dir(FLDR & "*RB*.xlsx")
    If Len(f) > 0 Then
        rgTarget.FormulaArray = "='" & FLDR & "\[" & f & "]Sheet1'!" & rgTarget.Address(True, True)
        rgTarget.Formula = rgTarget.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "No source file detected"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i've used your code, it download copied data but as #ADR! - not as value. Is there any way to update that code ?

Comment: It works fine for me when using "C:\Temp\" as the source folder (ie. Excel is not auto-adding a double backslash just before the `[` in the formula), but not when using my desktop.  I wonder if it's related to OneDrive syncing....

Comment: What i see in formula text in downloaded range is : ='\\FOLDER[2023.W04 SEPM RA Production Plan_Jan.24th.xlsx]Production Plan RA'!$B$23:$EA$6000 . So copying is working, only data is not correct cause i see no value but #REF! (wrong reference)